# How to stop cordova.contacts contacts.find getting all contact photos?

Tags: android, ios, cordova, cordova-plugins

We are not including photos as an option in our .find but the cordova.contacts plugin still gets all of the contact photos and puts them into temporary folders.

On phones where all contacts have photos this can take 10 seconds or more and fills up the memory... often crashing the device if it has to run a second time.

At the moment I am having to completely remove any part of the plugin that mentions the photos, as such it is all or nothing instead of just being able to get back a photo for chosen contacts.

So in summary
- cordova.contacts always gets all contact photos even if you don't say you want them
- what can be done to disable that when spooling the entire address book
- but still have the ability to call in a photo for specific contacts when needed

Is this perhaps a bug?

Comment: Have you tried passing the param `desiredFields` excluding the photo from the list of fields you would like returned?

Comment: Yes indeed - and we do only get back that data in the array, however it appears that the find still gets everything in the first place before returning that array... and thus causes the massive delay and memory issues on phones with lots of contacts with images etc.

Answer (score 0):

As per the [docs](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-contacts/blob/master/doc/index.md#navigatorcontactsfind), use **contactFindOptions.desiredFields** parameter to control which contact properties must be returned back.

Comment: Yes, we are using that, however the find still actually gets all the information and creates temporary folders for ALL of the photos still. We can see it happening in the memory view of Xcode and then see all the folders it is creating... even though we are not asking for the photo.